# How does Bootstrap-4 replace an html checkmark entity with its own?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use the HTML entity `&#10004;` to create a checkmark. Before adding Bootstrap to my page, the entity displays as a simple black checkmark, which is what I want. Bootstrap changes it to a black-bordered green checkbox with sharp corners. I can't figure out how Bootstrap does that. The entity code is not in the bootstrap.js file. I can find a workaround, but I'd really like to understand how Bootstrap does this.[image: Before and after]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the check mark modification is being accomplished by something other than Bootstrap.

Here is a standard Bootstrap 4.6.0 installation. On my computer (Mac OS 11.1), the check mark is unchanged from its default:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body class="p-4">
  Here is a check mark (&amp;#10004;): "&#10004;"
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your huckleberry:

```
body {
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",
      Arial,"Noto Sans","Liberation Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji",
      "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
}
```

You can override it with CSS:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
.other-font {font-family: Arial;}
</style>

<body class="p-4">
  <p class="other-font">Here is a check mark (&amp;#10004;): "&#10004;"</p>
</body>
```